# repositioning text boxes in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good morning everyone,

Sorry not sure how to word the question.
I have came across this problem, I can't seem to make the 'your email' box and 'your password' box align together. When you preview it in full screen, it will be how I want it but when I shrink the screen they start to go weird. Like this:

[image: I want it like this but on a big screen]
I want it like this but on a big screen

[image: This is what happens on a big screen]
This is what happens on a big screen

I would like it so they are both under each other and both in the same place. Please could you help me?

Please visit http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/8S5VG/ to see my code so far.

```
#top_box
{
background: grey;
height: 50px;
left: 80.8%;
width:20%;
position: relative;
top: 0;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: there is space at starting remove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in your HTML like unnecessary spacing and invalid tag names. I made it good. Replace your html with the following HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="top_box">
            <div class="homeform">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password">
                <input type="Submit" value="Login">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div id="menu_box"></div>
        <div id="main_box"></div>
        <div id="Bottom_box"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And also remove `height` from `#top_box`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8S5VG/3/)

Answer (score 0):

add line break between the two input boxes

```
<input ... />
<br />
<input .../>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8S5VG/1/

or make the inputs to `display:block`

[you had a slight mistake in the css]

http://jsfiddle.net/8S5VG/2/#update

Answer (score 0):

you calling homeform as an ID is you css but in your html it is a class replace the # with a . before homeform
you also have extra spacings that are moving the boxes, clean your html get rid of all unnecessary spaces

```
.homeform
{
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
    width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tyr This

```
#top_box {
background: grey;
min-height: 50px;
min-width: 164px;
left: 80.8%;
width: 20%;
position: relative;
top: 0;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Give in enough space for the inputs to be in place.

Hope this helps. if you need further assistance just let me know.

Comment: @xiiJaMiiE : Just reserve enough space for the html elements as in the css allow. Give in the required min-height and min-width